# Syntax Error for Create Table in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax

I am trying to create a new table in mySQL, and it shows me this error:

> A closing bracket was expected (near )).

Referring to the closing bracket followed by the semi-colon. I think it has something to do with the CONSTRAINTS line as it goes away when I remove them.

```
CREATE TABLE 'User' (
'FName' varchar(10),
'LName' varchar(10),
'Email' varchar(20), 
'Phone' int(20), 
'Password' varchar(20),
'Address' varchar(100),
'BuyerNum' int(3),
'SellerNum' int(3),
  CONSTRAINT 'User_FName_nn' NOT NULL('FName')
  CONSTRAINT 'User_LName_nn' NOT NULL('LName'),
  CONSTRAINT 'User_Email_pk' PRIMARY KEY('Email'),
  CONSTRAINT 'User_Phone_uk' UNIQUE('Phone'),
  CONSTRAINT 'User_Pass_nn' NOT NULL('Pass')
);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql

Comment: You have a missing comma after this line: `CONSTRAINT 'User_FName_nn' NOT NULL('FName')`. You should also use backticks, not single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma after this line: CONSTRAINT 'User_FName_nn' NOT NULL('FName')

```
CREATE TABLE 'User' (
'FName' varchar(10),
'LName' varchar(10),
'Email' varchar(20), 
'Phone' int(20), 
'Password' varchar(20),
'Address' varchar(100),
'BuyerNum' int(3),
'SellerNum' int(3),
  CONSTRAINT 'User_FName_nn' NOT NULL('FName')    <--- ,
  CONSTRAINT 'User_LName_nn' NOT NULL('LName'),
  CONSTRAINT 'User_Email_pk' PRIMARY KEY('Email'),
  CONSTRAINT 'User_Phone_uk' UNIQUE('Phone'),
  CONSTRAINT 'User_Pass_nn' NOT NULL('Pass')
);
```

And as others have said:

- You should use back ticks (`) instead of single quotes (').
- Moving the constraints into the definition will make it more readable and less confusing.
- You should have a UserId auto_increment column as the primary key instead of using the email column.

Gordon Linoff's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49028619/3763021) provides a few nice tips that you should definitely look into and understand why you want to use them as you go forward designing the rest of your database.

Edit: An alternate solution would be as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE User2 (
UserId int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
FName varchar(10) NOT NULL,
LName varchar(10),
Email varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
Phone int(20), 
Password varchar(20)NOT NULL,
Address varchar(100),
BuyerNum int(3),
SellerNum int(3)
);
```

Comment: This will still cause issues because of the single quotes.

Comment: Must use backtick \` not single quote.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues here, and I don't think the error does disappear when you remove the `CONSTRAINT` clauses. You're using single quotes (`'`) instead of backticks (`` ` ``).

You are also missing a comma after your first `CONSTRAINT` clause. Update as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
`FName` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`LName` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`Email` varchar(20), 
`Phone` int(20), 
`Password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Address` varchar(100),
`BuyerNum` int(3),
`SellerNum` int(3),
  CONSTRAINT `User_Email_pk` PRIMARY KEY(`Email`),
  CONSTRAINT `User_Phone_uk` UNIQUE(`Phone`)
);
```

Notice that we also removed the `CONSTRAINT` clauses for `NOT NULL`, and rather added them to the column definition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a comma after the end of your first `CONSTRAINT` line.

Answer (score 0):

```html
You Forgot , after 
CONSTRAINT 'User_FName_nn' NOT NULL('FName') this
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quote and add NOT NULL to the desired fields.

And, if possible do not use reserved words.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE User_Account 
> (
> FName varchar(10) NOT NULL,
> LName varchar(10) NOT NULL,
> Email varchar(20), 
> Phone int(20), 
> Password varchar(20) NOT NULL,
> Address varchar(100),
> BuyerNum int(3),
> SellerNum int(3),
>   CONSTRAINT User_Email_pk PRIMARY KEY(Email),
>   CONSTRAINT User_Phone_uk UNIQUE(Phone)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=426e7a83a9b8e4cadedd32682ad0d95c)*

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume that the single quotes are all typos in the question.

Second, put these short constraints in the column definitions, unless you have a really strong urge to name them:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    FName varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    LName varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    Email varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY, 
    Phone varchar(20) UNIQUE, 
    Password varchar(20) NOT NULL,  -- should be encrypted
    Address varchar(100),
    BuyerNum int(3),
    SellerNum int(3)
);
```

When you split the definition, it makes it harder to figure out how a given column is really defined.  "Oh, it is a string that accepts `NULL` values.  Wait!  It is also `NOT NULL`.  Wait!  It is also `UNIQUE`."

I also changed the `phone` to a string.  Some numbers begin with "0"s or "+", for instance.

Also, you should have a `userId` as the first column:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    UserId int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    FName varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    LName varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    Email varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    Phone varchar(20) UNIQUE, 
    Password varchar(20) NOT NULL,  -- should be encrypted
    Address varchar(100),
    BuyerNum int(3),
    SellerNum int(3)
);
```

Why?

- Your structure does not allow a user to change their email (because as the primary key it is referenced in other tables).
- Strings are less efficient in foreign key indexes.

Answer (score 0):

just put a (comma) , after every CONSTRAINT except the last CONSTRAINT.
such that: 
CONSTRAINT 'User_FName_nn' NOT NULL('FName'),

Answer (score 0):

Table name does not need single quotes, and u are missing an comma as suggested by everyone else after first line of constraints.

Here...
CREATE TABLE user ( FName varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 LName varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
Email varchar(20),
 Phone int(20), 
Password varchar(20) NOT NULL, Address varchar(100), 
BuyerNum int(3), 
SellerNum int(3), 
CONSTRAINT User_Email_pk PRIMARY KEY(Email), 
CONSTRAINT User_Phone_uk UNIQUE(Phone) );